# Add subquery to CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
declare @nodeid int = '1';

with cte as 
(
    select  
        cust_ID, name, null lnode, null rnode 
    from  
        user_detail 
    where 
        cust_ID = @nodeid 

    union all 

    select 
        t.cust_ID, t.name, 
        isnull(cte.lnode, case when t.joinside = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
        lnode, 
        isnull(cte.rnode, case when t.joinside = 1 then 1 else 0 end),
        rnode 
    from  
        user_detail t 
    inner join 
        cte on cte.cust_ID = t.parentid 
)
select 
    cust_ID, name 
from 
    cte 
where 
    rnode = '0' 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Current scenario:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I will explain what I want: the above query is getting results only from `user_detail` table. I want to modify the query in such a way that it will also search in `installments` table for the `status` column of the respective `cust_id`.

The modified query will get the value of status from installments table based on `cust_id`.

And query will show the results in the third column as showing in 2nd screenshot.

I am not very familiar with CTE and nested queries. I hope you guys will understand my problem.

Comment: could you please provide sample data or structure of your table

Comment: please go through the screenshots

Comment: first of all screenshots are not good way to post question and also you've not provid your installment table structure. So you know it's difficult to answer based on assumption

Comment: there are only two columns in the installments table cust_id and status..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
declare @nodeid int = '1';
with cte as ( 
select  cust_ID, name,null lnode, null rnode from  user_detail where 
cust_ID = @nodeid 

union all select t.cust_ID,t.name, ISNULL(cte.lnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 
0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
lnode, ISNULL(cte.rnode, CASE WHEN t.joinside = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
rnode from  user_detail t inner join cte on cte.cust_ID = t.parentid )

select cust_ID,name,status from cte c
inner join installment i on c.cust_id=i.cust_id
where rnode='0' 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: it is not giving desired results

Comment: that's why I asked your table structure @HarpreetSingh

Answer (score 0):

At the End you can Join with wvery table

```
select 
    cust_ID, name ,Table.status
from cte 
Join Table on Table. cust_ID  = cte.cust_ID 
where 
  rnode = '0'
```